# Authenticating requests to Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer

Tags: authentication, owin

I'm using the owin TestServer class to unit test my web api.  It's working great except that I'm unsure how to authenticate requests, so I can't really test endpoints that require authentication, other than to make sure that unauthenticated requests are unauthorized.

I am configuring WebApi to use only bearer token authentication as indicated here:

```
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Any ideas how I could do this easily?

Comment: Wow, I've just hit a very similar issue and one of the few google hits is asked just 8 hours ago :) I've just moved to OWIN - before I was just using in memory HttpServer for integration tests and "Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClientRolePrincipal" but this doesn't seem to work with Katana\OWIN.  Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not.  If you vote up the question it should get it more exposure, and I plan on putting a bounty on it when eligible!

Comment: Done.  I found a workaround for my issue, no idea if it will help you and it's certainly not optimal, but perhaps it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897705/authentication-with-microsoft-owin-testing-testserver-for-in-memory-integration/19920179#19920179

Comment: Any solution is better than no solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found useful documentation to use TestServer+OAuth authentication
http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2014-01-12-integration-testing-katana-with-auth/

He also provides whole VS solution at GitHub.
https://github.com/aaronpowell/Owin.AuthenticatedTests/tree/a154931dd82e5180daf7163c2129f3a90401df55