# Authentication with Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer for In-Memory Integration Tests

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I've just moved to using OWIN\Katana for a web api project. It uses Windows Authentication.  This seems to be working, but most of my integration tests have broken.   They were previously just using an In-Memory `HttpServer` but I've changed to using `Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer`.  I've replaced something like this in my test setup:

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration { IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always };
        config.EnableQuerySupport();
        Server = new HttpServer(config);
        MyConfigClass.Configure(config);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

with a simpler:

```
TestServer = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
```

But whereas previously I could just put the following to "fake" authentication with the in-memory server:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClientRolePrincipal(new HttpListenerBasicIdentity(Username, Password));
```

This now doesn't work.  I get the following for all requests:

```
System.Exception : {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

How do I Authenticate with the In-Memory OWIN test server or at least by-pass the authentication?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've been able to workaround this in a way that I'm sure is sub-optimal, but will have to do until I come across a better solution or one of you fine folk tells me a better way to do this :)   I've done it as follows:

1. In my Startup class I've added a CreateAuthFilter hook which we'll see later is used only in integration tests:

   ```
   // Sample Startup class
   public class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           var config = new HttpConfiguration();

           // Use CreateFilter Method to create Authorisation Filter -  if not null add it
           var authFilter = CreateAuthFilter();
           if(authFilter != null)
               config.Filters.Add(authFilter);

           // Other configuration and middleware...
       }

       public static Func<IFilter> CreateAuthFilter = () => null;
   }
   ```
2. Implemented an Authorization Filter which will only be used in Integration Tests:

   ```
   public class TestAuthFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
   {
       static TestAuthFilter()
       {
           TestUserId = "TestDomain\\TestUser";
       }

       public bool AllowMultiple { get; private set; }

       public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           context.Principal = new ClientRolePrincipal(new HttpListenerBasicIdentity(TestUserId, "password")); ;
       }

       public static string TestUserId { get; set; }

       public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {

       }
   }
   ```
3. In the SetUp code for my Integration Tests I inject the Test Authorization Filter:

   ```
   Startup.CreateAuthFilter = () => new TestAuthFilter();
   var TestServer = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
   ```
4. When needed in specific tests, I set the TestUserId to a known value, and other tests just seem to work because the Auth Filter is present:

   ```
   TestAuthFilter.TestUserId = testUser.UserId;
   ```

I'm sharing this here incase it helps others out there, but please someone tell me a better way! At the very least I'm sure there's a better way to inject my Test Filter without including code in Startup... I just haven't thought of it.

Comment: Could you open source a project demonstrating integration tests using OWIN?

Comment: Sure I'll see if I can put something simple together in the next couple of days, and edit the answer above with a link when I do. If I haven't done so within a couple of days, can you email me a reminder? simon1979 (at) the mail from google.

Comment: Genius. Thank you for this - it was driving me nuts trying to figure out how to get a mock user to show up in the context. Instead of ClientRolePrincipal I opted for GenericPrinicpal which is what MVC assigns normally.